# Can I turn auto-shrink off while on production server with people connected?

Tags: sql-server

I'm going to turn auto-shrink off on our SQL Server 2008, but I was wondering if I need to wait until the end of the day when no one is on the server? Or, can I just make the change now? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to admit I expected this to require a lock on the database which would mean you couldn't do it while someone else was in the database.  But just to be certain I did some testing and was able to update the setting while I had an open transaction on a table in the database.

So technically yes you could make the change during the day.  However, just because you can doesn't mean you should.  In general any changes like that should wait until after hours (or a maintenance window).  Unless of course auto_shrink is causing you production issues that you don't feel like you can wait on.

It's definitely a good idea to turn it off as soon as you can.  There are a few edge cases I've heard of where it's helpful but not very many.

Answer (score 1):

I would wait until the end of the day and then turn off auto shrink and never turn it back on. If you are low on disk space you will need to look into to getting some more and then turning auto shrink off.

The reason for this is it creates a lot of fragmentation. See [this](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/auto-shrink-turn-it-off/) to see how bad this can be.

Answer (score 1):

I'd err on the side of caution and do it at the end of the day.  May not make a difference but anytime I switch settings like that, I just wait for the evening when i have my maintenance window.

Good for you for turning it off!

Comment: I don't think I would wait. Even if turning this off causes some kind of disruption (which others have confirmed does not happen), wouldn't it be worse to have 10 auto-shrink operations somehow triggered between now and the end of the day?

Comment: It would be worse, sure.  I always choose to go the safe route when i change any stuff like this, just personal preference.